# SQL Server update from table to table

Tags: sql-server

I want to update the Main table (tbl_MN_Omega_Raw) using a Temporary Table (tbl_MN_Daily_SLA) based on Request_ID, so if the Request_ID from Temporary Table exist on the Main Table, the info on the other 19 columns will be updated too but I ran into a problem which all of the Request_ID is being update but the info/details is based on the 3 transactions I have in my Temporary Table. Here's my code below. Thanks in advance!

Main Table after update:
[enter image description here][1]

Temporary Table:
[enter image description here][2]

```
UPDATE [tbl_MN_Omega_Raw]
SET  
     Issuing_Country_Name = Y.Issuing_Country_Name
    ,Program_Stucture_Name = Y.Program_Structure
    ,Line_Of_Business_Name = Y.Line_Of_Business_Name
    ,Request_Gross_Premium_Amount = Y.Request_Gross_Premium_Amount
    ,Request_Collection_Currency_Name = Y.Request_Collection_Currency_Name
    ,Client_name = Y.Client_name
    ,RO_Service_Contact = Y.RO_Service_Contact
    ,Request_Effective_Date = Y.Request_Effective_Date
    ,Request_Release_Date = Y.Request_Effective_Date
    ,Original_Request_Release_Date = Y.Original_Request_Release_Date
    ,Request_Type = Y.Request_Type
    ,Request_Status = Y.Request_Status
    ,Request_Reject_Date = Y.Request_Reject_Date
    ,Request_Reject_Reason = Y.Request_Correction_Date
    ,Request_Correction_Date = Y.Request_Accepted_Date
    ,Request_Accepted_Date = Y.Request_Local_Book_Date
    ,Request_Local_Book_Date = Y.Request_Local_Book_Date
    ,Policy_Issued_Date = Y.Policy_Issued_Date
    ,IO_Account_Handler_Contact = Y.IO_Account_Handler_Contact
FROM tbl_MN_Daily_SLA Y
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tbl_MN_Omega_Raw X WHERE X.Request_ID = Y.Request_ID) 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pShmt.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0Paz.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `WHERE` clause, instead `join` your temporary on your main table:

```
UPDATE [tbl_MN_Omega_Raw]
SET  
     Issuing_Country_Name = Y.Issuing_Country_Name
    ,Program_Stucture_Name = Y.Program_Structure
    ,Line_Of_Business_Name = Y.Line_Of_Business_Name
    ,Request_Gross_Premium_Amount = Y.Request_Gross_Premium_Amount
    ,Request_Collection_Currency_Name = Y.Request_Collection_Currency_Name
    ,Client_name = Y.Client_name
    ,RO_Service_Contact = Y.RO_Service_Contact
    ,Request_Effective_Date = Y.Request_Effective_Date
    ,Request_Release_Date = Y.Request_Effective_Date
    ,Original_Request_Release_Date = Y.Original_Request_Release_Date
    ,Request_Type = Y.Request_Type
    ,Request_Status = Y.Request_Status
    ,Request_Reject_Date = Y.Request_Reject_Date
    ,Request_Reject_Reason = Y.Request_Correction_Date
    ,Request_Correction_Date = Y.Request_Accepted_Date
    ,Request_Accepted_Date = Y.Request_Local_Book_Date
    ,Request_Local_Book_Date = Y.Request_Local_Book_Date
    ,Policy_Issued_Date = Y.Policy_Issued_Date
    ,IO_Account_Handler_Contact = Y.IO_Account_Handler_Contact
FROM tbl_MN_Daily_SLA Y
inner join tbl_MN_Omega_Raw X 
ON X.Request_ID = Y.Request_ID
```

Comment: ohh never tried that. Anyway does it only apply when the Request_ID is existing? Thats why I use "Where Exists" since I only want to update those transaction with same Request_ID.

Comment: @MrNimbus I would suggest reading about `joins`, but yes, `inner join`: "Inner joins result in the overlapping part of the Venn diagram of two datasets" So it will only look at records that exist in both datasets (tables). Here's a link for learning about `joins`: [sql-joins](https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-joins/)

Comment: Hello, i've tried inner join but im still having the same results :(

Comment: @MrNimbus You shouldn't be, please provide sample data. You already updated your main table once and mistakenly updated all the rows with the wrong data, so unless you rolled back these changes you probably won't see any difference.

Comment: hello I replaced all my data and it actually works! I just didnt noticed it first since all my data have the same value. Thanks a lot what a life saver!!